# Ubuntu 14 desktop install failed and corrupted grub

Tags: grub2, windows, 14.04, system-installation, windows-vista

Long story:

Tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. 12 already installed. Dual boot system with Vista.

Install failed. Now I cannot boot to either 14 or Vista. Grub rescue only prompt available.

Tried `sudo add-apt-repsotitory ppa:yannubuntu/boot repair`. It could not find boot repair

Tried `update`. No go.

Tried `install`. No go.

Ubuntu will not install again either.

Desperately need to get windows back. Files system shows Windows system intact. Grub seems to be the issue.

Comment: The command is not `add-apt-repsotitory` but `add-apt-repository`!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04 over older ubuntu 14.04 and is this installation goes good you will have your grub repaired and will be able to access Windows also

On the other hand if you just want to access windows and do not care about ubuntu then do [Grub Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)